# Jquery map slow on binding with JSknockout

Tags: jquery

when am trying to map a semi large set of data I notice it is slow .. the browser will even freeze for few seconds . I am not sure if it is from Jquery map  or the knockout

I think that this part where it slows

```
model.Entries($.map(data.Entries, function (e, i) { return new  FieldFormatEntry(e.Name, e.HasTransformationList,e.Caption, e.HeaderName, e.Format, e.AcceptedFormats); }));
```

here is the code

```
function FieldFormatEntry(name,transformationList,caption, headerName, format, acceptedFormats) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Caption = ko.observable(caption);
    self.HeaderName = ko.observable(headerName).extend({ required: true });
    self.Format = ko.observable(format).extend({ required: true });
    self.AcceptedFormats = ko.observableArray();
if (acceptedFormats !== null && acceptedFormats.length > 0)
    {
        var formats = ko.utils.arrayMap(acceptedFormats,function(item) {
            return item;
        });
        self.AcceptedFormats.push.apply(self.AcceptedFormats, formats);
}`enter code here`
    self.hasTransformationList = transformationList;
    self.hasAcceptedFormatsList = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.AcceptedFormats().length > 0;
    }, this);
}

function dataSet() {
    var self = this;
    self.Entries = ko.observableArray();
    self.showTip = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.Entries().length > 1);
    }, this);
}



    function fillAndBindEntries(data) {
    var model = new dataSet();
    model.Entries($.map(data.Entries, function (e, i) { return new                       FieldFormatEntry(e.Name, e.HasTransformationList,e.Caption, e.HeaderName, e.Format, e.AcceptedFormats); }));
    ko.applyBindings(model);
}
```

Any ideas ? how can I improve the performance

Comment: I'm not sure what you define by "semi large set of data". How many data.Entries ?

Comment: This is a prime case for using a javascript profiler. Chrome and IE both have nice profiling tools.

Comment: well over 100 Entries . even over 50 you start seeing the difference

Comment: Your issue _could_ be with `self.AcceptedFormats.push(acceptedFormats[i]);`. Generally, pushing elements into an `observableArray` within a loop is a bad idea, though that may only be a problem after applying bindings.

Comment: @ Jason P Thanks man I totally forgot about the push i will try to change the code and see if changes the performance will let you know

Comment: i changed the push to  self.AcceptedFormats.push.apply(self.AcceptedFormats, formats); No luck